# How to update a record with known $key in angularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a record in my firebase dB that I want to update. Because I am binding the player object to UI components which I don't want to refresh before the update is submitted, I made a clone copy of the real firebase record as follows:

```
newPlayerWithSameKey(p: Player): any {
    const origKey = (<any>p).$key;
    const duplicate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p))
    duplicate.$key = (<any>p).$key;
    return duplicate;
}
```

If I log this in the console, `p` and `duplicate` are exactly the same.
The duplicate is then injected into the update method on my data service handling the records. I am trying to update it this way:

```
updatePlayer(player: Player): void {
    const key = this.getKey(player);

    // The following three lines are just for the console log to demonstrate
    let shouldBeThePlayerToBeUpdated;
    this.db.object('/players/' + key).subscribe(p => shouldBeThePlayerToBeUpdated = p);
    window.console.log('Mock player: ', key, JSON.stringify(shouldBeThePlayerToBeUpdated));

    window.console.log('Updating player with key: ', key, JSON.stringify(player));
    this.db.list('/players').update(key, player)
}

private getKey(p: Player): string {
    return (<any>p).$key
}
```

But I get the following error: As you can see the keys match exactly, and the firstName property is being updated correctly (that is what I did in the form). I am really confused what the problem is here ... Anybody have an idea?

[image]

Comment: try  this.db.object('/players/'+key).update(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

```
this.db.list('/players').update(key, player)
```

by

```
this.db.object('/players/'+key).update(player)
```

EDIT:

```
this.db.object('/players').update({'/'+key, player})
```

One example of: how I use it:

```
const update = {
    'starsNumber': someValue + 1
}
update[`level/${photo_id}/photo_id`] = photo_id
}

firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`game/users/${admin_id}/players/${user.id}/`)
    .update(update)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get exactly the same error message, it does not work.

Comment: @Wandrille but in the`this.db.list('/players').update({'/'+key, player})` the `list('/players')` will get all the players and then `update({'/'+key, player})` the single document right.correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan I you are worried about the workload, don't. `list('/players')` gets a reference to the list of players (better: to the Observable emitting lists of players) and does not really fetch them all.

Comment: @EluciusFTW very clear , so once we subscribe, then only it fetches all the records right?

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan Technically, once we subscribe the db emits then to us, we don't fetch them.

Comment: @Wandrille I tried your newest edit too, but it also does not work, same error.

Comment: @EluciusFTW I write you how I use it. If it doesnt work. Are you sure about the key?